# Tengo un error en mi sintaxis de mi SQL. MARIADB

Tags: sql, mariadb

estaba generando data para algunos ejemplos con algunos procesos, sin embargo, no sé por qué este me sale error, tal parece que es terminando el FOR o la verdad no sé dónde, he revisado sin tener éxito, por favor ayudadme. Gracias de antemano.

**Error de SQL (1064): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'FOR for_label;
SET id= id+1;
END FOR for_label1;
END' at line 40**

```
delimiter $$
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE cargar_libro_diario()
BEGIN
    DECLARE id NUMERIC(9);
    DECLARE band NUMERIC(5);
    DECLARE rcuo NUMERIC(10);
    SET rcuo = 1;
    SET id=14;
    SET band=1;
    for_label1: FOR fila1 IN (SELECT cpar.id_cuenta_party, cpar.debe, cpar.haber, cpar.id_comprobante_pago FROM cuenta_party cpar WHERE cpar.id_cuenta_party !=1)
    DO
        for_label: FOR fila IN(SELECT f.fecha FROM fechas f)
        DO
            if band=1 then
                INSERT INTO libro_diario(CUO, periodo, id_asiento_contable, id_cuenta_party, id_party, id_rol_party,
                id_comprobante_pago, fecha_contable, fecha_vencimiento, descripcion, movimiento_debe, movimiento_haber,
                id_estado_operacion, comentario)
                VALUES(rcuo, MONTH(fila.fecha), 2, 1, 1, 1, NULL, fila.fecha, LAST_DAY(fila.fecha), NULL, 100, 0, 1, NULL),
                (rcuo+1, MONTH(fila.fecha), 2, fila1.id_cuenta_party, id, id, NULL, fila.fecha, LAST_DAY(fila.fecha), NULL, 0, 100, 1, NULL);
                SET rcuo= rcuo+1;
            ELSE if band=2 then
                INSERT INTO libro_diario(CUO, periodo, id_asiento_contable, id_cuenta_party, id_party, id_rol_party,
                id_comprobante_pago, fecha_contable, fecha_vencimiento, descripcion, movimiento_debe, movimiento_haber,
                id_estado_operacion, comentario)
                VALUES(rcuo, MONTH(fila.fecha), 3, fila1.id_cuenta_party, id, id, fila1.id_comprobante_pago, fila.fecha, LAST_DAY(fila.fecha), NULL, fila1.debe, 0, 1, NULL),
                (rcuo+1, MONTH(fila.fecha), 3, 1, 1, 1, fila1.id_comprobante_pago, fila.fecha, LAST_DAY(fila.fecha), NULL, 0, fila1.debe, 1, NULL);
                SET rcuo= rcuo+1;
            ELSE
                INSERT INTO libro_diario(CUO, periodo, id_asiento_contable, id_cuenta_party, id_party, id_rol_party,
                id_comprobante_pago, fecha_contable, fecha_vencimiento, descripcion, movimiento_debe, movimiento_haber,
                id_estado_operacion, comentario)
                VALUES(rcuo, MONTH(fila.fecha), 1, fila1.id_cuenta_party, id, id, NULL, fila.fecha, LAST_DAY(fila.fecha), NULL, 0, fila1.haber-100, 1, NULL);
                SET band=1;
                SET rcuo= rcuo+1;
                leave for_label;
            END if;
            
            SET rcuo= rcuo+1;
            SET band= band+1;
            
        END FOR for_label;
        SET id= id+1;
    END FOR for_label1;
END;
$$
```

Answer (score 1):

ya vi mi error. El problema estaba en la sintaxis de IF
cuando se hace un "ELSEIF" se coloca junto, no separado (ELSE IF).